# WebSocket.close is broken in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

According to the WebSocket Draft-76 spec, Wocket.close is supposed to do the following:

"To close the connection cleanly, a frame consisting of just a 0xFF byte followed by a 0×00 byte is sent from one peer to ask that the other peer close the connection."

But, after a few tests, I don’t think that Chrome is doing anything when closed is called. I’m curious if I’m doing something wrong or if it’s a known bug.

Comment: I observe the same behaviour on Chromium (Linux) as of december 30th 2011.. Really annoying!

Comment: Safari seems to close them, Chrome & Firefox, for me anyways, hang on to the connections after close is called :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed any issues when testing with Chrome. I haven't inspected the frames either though.

Answer (score 0):

i know this topic is really old, but I noticed that Chrome is the only browser, which doesnt send 0xff00 at socket close command... instead it closes its socket conn on browser side, so if I notice, that a "chrome" user is offline, if i failt to receive data from that socket. Just my two cents :)